# run spark application locally via sbt

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, shuffle, java-opts

I want to run a spark job locally for testing. If `spark-submit` and a assembled jar are used it works just fine.

However if `sbt run` is used I get a very strange error https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/946dd7706f44f338101c8332f4e13c1a

Trying to set java-opts like

```
javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xms512M", "-Xmx2048M", "-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M", "-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled")
```

Did not help to solve the problem.

Trying to fiddle with memory settings in `local[*]` mode like

```
.set("spark.executor.memory", "7g")
.set("spark.driver.memory", "7g")
```

did only spawn further problems of `ExecutorLostFailure`

Comment: Do you have ```fork in run := true``` set in your build.sbt?

Comment: Indeed, that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never ran into this issue specifically but I think spark code is not made to be run with `sbt run`. I even remember reading about it in the docs but could not find it as of now.

I guess what you should do instead is compiling it with sbt and use `spark-submit` instead.

Comment: But when a spark-job is embedded via an actor in a play-framework application how would you start it in such a context?

Comment: I have no experience with the play framework unfortunately. Can not be of help here.

Comment: Or with akka. The point I want to make is: it is not a single one-off spark job but integrated into an scala application.

Comment: You could try using something like the sparklauncher which is used to start spark jobs from within Java or Scala code. An example can be found here: https://blog.knoldus.com/2015/06/26/startdeploy-apache-spark-application-programmatically-using-spark-launcher/

Comment: Very interesting @OberstK however, if I understand correctly sparkLauncher still requires to assemble the jar. And then a spark-submit is equally simple (for testing purposes)

Comment: Absolutely. For testing purposes spark-submit seems the way to go. Only other way may be using the spark shell on its own but that one is pretty limited.